# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in ..Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php on line 72

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, entrust

I've just installed **Entrust** to add Role-based Permissions to my application based on **Laravel 5.2**. But when I try to execute

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

I get this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  " Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in ../vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php on line 72 "

can anyone help me?

Comment: To fix it .i executed `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using previous version that is not compatible with Laravel 5.1.+. Make sure you are using latest version or run `composer update zizaco/entrust` to update this package to latest version that is defined in `composer.json`

If you look at [this commit](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/commit/c65d6cc0cbd44d775e991489fc2047f1ed61d145) you will set it has been already changed a while ago.

Answer (score 5):

just repalce bindShared() with singleton()

Comment: in which file to change this?

Comment: @AhmedRaza in this file: `vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php` just change `bindShared()` to `singleton()`

Answer (score 0):

I have researched more and got solution you need update function name only.

**vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php**

```
$this->app->bindShared('form', function($app)
```

To

```
$this->app->singleton('form', function($app)
```

on line number : 36 and 40

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2 and i can't find vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php, do you have any idea where this setting is?